# Thread Safety of Java I/O PrintStream

Tags: java, io, thread-safety

I have code which prints to a file using `PrintStream`. Each thread spawns its own version of `PrintStream`. I know that normally operating systems (linux in my case) lock files for write permission. Is this the case in java? Or in other words, is the following code thread safe?

```
private void writeToFile(String data) {
    File file = new File("/file.out");
    try {
        if (!file.exists()) {
            //if file doesnt exist, create it
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(file, true));
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date date = new Date();
        out.println(dateFormat.format(date) + " " + data);

        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Before you answer, here are a couple of assumptions you can make:

1. Limiting to one `PrintStream` is not possible. Please make the assumption that there WILL be multiple instances of it, and that can't change. On the same note, this one method can not be synchronized. I don't want answers that just say "synchronize your code".
2. If the OS does lock the file for write permissions, does it lock it upon the request to write or when the `File` is instantiated. In other words, does the lock get released when the writing is done or when `out.close()` is called?

Comment: Java is `platform-independent`, it will do **different** things on different platforms. If its not written in the spec, you have to assume that the behavior may vary between both **implementations** and **versions** of java. From my experience, Java 7 on Windows 7 locks a file until the `close()` is invoked.

Comment: You don't need to call `createNewFile()` before creating a `FileOutputStream` or `FileWriter`. It's just repeating what they already do, so it's wasteful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Linux multiple processes can write to a file at the same time. There is no locking by default, and buffering in the application layer may produce unpredictable results.

On Windows files can be opened with a sharing mode that permits another process from opening the file for writing at the same time. The "lock" would be set when the file is opened in the CreateFile Windows API function. If I recall correctly Java uses this mode by default, so that two processes can open a file for writing at the same time.

Use the file locking API for predictable, platform independent results.

Comment: Thanks. So your basically saying the code above is NOT safe on a linux environment.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by safe: the data will get to the file. The problem is the output from one process can be interrupted by another, though apparently small writes should be atomic (http://linux.die.net/man/3/write).  I would expect the same thing happens on Windows.